# How to resolve Vue.js devtools not working in the Electron Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-devtools

When I run the project by `npm run electron:serve`, the components tree of the `Vue.js devtools` and other tabs are empty. Actually it dose not detect the project.

How can I solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Terminate the project and add the following line *before* the `new Vue(...)` in `main.js` file the run the project again by `npm run electron:serve` command.

```
Vue.config.devtools = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```

[image]

Result: